# How to use HRTF in an application

Tags: wpf, database, audio

I'm trying to incorporate HRTF in an wpf application. I'm working with the MIT Kemar HRTF-dataset but have no idea how to use the wav-files that it is comprised of. I get the angle and elevation but then how do I use the wav-file to make my audio-file sound like it's coming from that specific directions?

if there is any easier way of using HRTF in wpf that would of course be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some sophisticated convolutions on your input signal. It's quite hard to explain here, so read some scientific articles associated with the MIT data set. We had a student here implementing them, so if you don't understand it, consider hiring someone with a academic background with signal/audio processing skills to do it.

I'm not familiair with specific implementations for wpf, but you may look for hardware-based solutions that make use of the same principles.